# spark combobox dataprovider validator

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I want to give validations to the spark combobox when user enters a value other than the value in the dataprovider of that combobox.Can any one give me the code how to give validation if user enters a value other than the value in the dataprovider and on focus change validation should occur.
Thanks

Comment: If you don't want a user to fill in other values, why don't you just use DropDownList?

Comment: The requirement is it should be editable and selectable but dropdownlist is not editable and also it doesnot get selected first time when user presses any character in the keyboard we should change the focus to get displayed the selected value in the DropDownList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the property `textInput` to the combobox, and manage the check on input from the associated function...

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function change(event:TextEvent):void
        {

        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:ComboBox  textInput="change(event)"/>
```

> flash.display.InteractiveObject.textInput
>
> Dispatched when a user enters one or more characters of text. Various text input methods can
>   generate this event, including standard keyboards, input method
>   editors (IMEs), voice or speech recognition systems, and even the act
>   of pasting plain text with no formatting or style information.
>
> **Event Type:**
>   flash.events.TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT

**EDIT**

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        //dataprovider initialization
        [Bindable]private var d:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {name: "Values 1"}, {name: "Values 2"}, {name: "Values 3"}
            ]);

        protected function change(event:TextEvent):void
        {      // if enter key is pressed
            if (event.text.charAt(event.text.length-1) == "\r")
            {       
                // if the text inserted in the combobox is one of the 
                // item in the dataprovider 
                if (comboBox.selectedIndex >= 0)
                    Alert.show("something selected");
                else   // if the text is not an item in the dataprovider
                    Alert.show("nothing selected");

            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:ComboBox id="comboBox" textInput="change(event)"
       dataProvider="{d}" labelField="name"/>
```

**EDIT 2**

To set the border color from actionscript you can do:

```
comboBox.setStyle("borderColor","#ff0000"); // set the bordercolor to red
```

If you do not need particular check on the text inserted you can simply set the property change on the ComboBox

```
        protected function index_change(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {
            if (comboBox.selectedIndex >= 0 )
                Alert.show("something selected")
            else
                Alert.show("nothing selected");

        }
        <s:ComboBox id="comboBox" dataProvider="{d}" labelField="name"
            change="index_change(event)"
             />
```

Comment: Hi Marcx thanks for ur answer but can u please tell me what i should write inside that change event handler inorder to throw a validation message to the user.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly what you need but you can do something like that... (check the edit in my answer)

Comment: Marcx thanks for reply again.U correctly understood what i was asking.I used ur code but now the problem is i also used change='indexChangeHandler(event)'; along with textInput="change(event)" but now when nothing is selected change event should not get called but currently it is getting called.How to stop that. Also it could be more helpful if u tell me how to give validation error with red border rather than showing in Alert.

Comment: Thank you very much. Lastly cant i use a string validator to determine whether user entered value is in the dataprovider of combobox so that i can give source to the string validator.Actually i have lot of comboboxes that are created dynamically so when user enters wrong values in the combobox and presses save button all validation errors should come as in string validator.